# Can we setup Knative cluster with Kata Container runtime?

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, knative, knative-serving, kata-containers

I'm a newbie to lightweight virtual machines. I'm going to install Knative with Kata Container Runtime. Is it possible?

I know that Kubernetes works with Kata Container runtime. But, Does Knative work properly with that?

Answer (score 2):

Knative should work fine with Kata Containers (I know of no incompatibility, and the runtime pods are pretty standard), but I don't think I've seen it tested or written up before.

Comment: Note that you may need to use some sort of policy to [set the appropriate runtime class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/runtime-class/); I'm not sure whether Knative allows these fields to be set directly.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it tested or written up before, but it should work fine with Kata